# BeautifulSoup order of occurrence of Tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Consider the following situation:

```
tag1 = soup.find(**data_attrs)
tag2 = soup.find(**delim_attrs)
```

Is there a way to find out which tag occurred "first" in the page?

Clarifications:

- For my purposes, the ordering is the same as that of beautifulsoup's findNext method. (I'm currently using this fact to "solve" my problem although it's hacky.)
- The purpose here is basically to accumulate tags that are not separated by a "delimiter tag". Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BeautifulSoup tags don't track their order in the page, no. You'd have to loop over all tags *again* and find your two tags in that list.

Using the standard [sample BeautifulSoup tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree):

```
>>> tag1 = soup.find(id='link1')
>>> tag2 = soup.find(id='link2')
>>> tag1, tag2
(<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>, <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>)
>>> all_tags = soup.find_all(True)
>>> all_tags.index(tag1)
6
>>> all_tags.index(tag2)
7
```

I'd use a `tag.find_all()` with a function to match both tag types instead; that way you get a list of the tags and can see their relative order:

```
tag_match = lambda el: (
    getattr(el, 'name', None) in ('tagname1', 'tagname2') and
    el.attrs.get('attributename') == 'something' and 
    'classname' in el.attrs.get('class')
)
tags = soup.find(tag_match)
```

or you can use the `.next_siblings` iterator to loop over all elements in the same parent and see if the delimiter comes next, etc.

Comment: This post is a bit old, but the .next_siblings solution only works if the two nodes found are at the same depth in the tree

Comment: @geoffn91: only for *siblings*, so same depth *with the same parent*. I do mention this in my answer: *to loop over all elements in the same parent*