# BeautifulSoup- find_all- Order Preservation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a website which has various classes of the same name. I would like to take the elements of the first( as seen on webpage ) class. However, find_all or find do not preserve the order of the parsing. Below is my implementation of find_all

Please help:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


searchQueryFK = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q="+str("panasonic%2043e200dx")
r = urllib.request.urlopen(searchQueryFK).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
FKPrice = soup.find_all("div", {'class':"_2SxMvQ"})[0].find_all("div", {'class':"_1vC4OE"})[0]

print(FKPrice.text[1:])
```

Comment: Surely they _do_ preserve the order. Can you produce a counterexample?

Comment: For example: let searchQueryFK be: 
searchQueryFK = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q="+str("58D300DX%20Panasonic"). I should get the print of 57,000. However, I am getting 8,999. In some other instance of the code run, I get some other number.

Comment: check the data received first. some sites give you different data when you are on browser or like in you, a scraper.

Comment: @nickanor it is not giving the data as is required. That is why the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does BeautifulSoup find\_all() preserve tag order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654837/does-beautifulsoup-find-all-preserve-tag-order)

Answer (score 0):

I would say I am not the most eligible person to comment on the performance, as `bs4` uses one construct which I am not very familiar with, namely `generator`.

Upon looking through the source code for beautiful soup ([github](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/master/bs4/element.py)), I see that the function iterates over some `generator`. Hence my conclusion is: if the generators preserve their orders, then so does find_all(), else vice-versa.

Just search `def find_all(`, in the source code, and do let me know, what sounds convincing to you.

But since the `range` function in python also returns a generator, hence I believe that generators preserve their order, hence my claim is that the `find_all` also preserves the order.

**But, I am not 100% sure.**