# Different ordering of scraped question-answers pair

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, quora

I am new to BeautifulSoup and scraping different question-answers pair from `Quora` on the topic **'GRE'** [link](https://www.quora.com/topic/Graduate-Record-Examination-GRE-1).

After scraping, I viewed the scraped question-answer pair and noticed that the ordering of the scraped pair is different from the one that is actually in the website.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654837/does-beautifulsoup-find-all-preserve-tag-order) question, the answer says that `find_all` does preserve the order, but using `find_all` didn't help preserve the order in my case.

Am I going wrong somewhere ? Kindly help !!

Here is the code for the scraping:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.quora.com/topic/Graduate-Record-Examination-GRE-1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())

#match = soup.title
#match
#match.text

#a = soup.find('link', id_ = 'wxlJClxd1')
#a = soup.find('div', class_ = 'AnswerStoryBundle Bundle')#.find('div', id_ = '__w2_waNcSF3r41_paged_list')
a = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'AnswerStoryBundle Bundle'})
for i in a:
    print(i.text,'\n')

---------
```

I can't understand why a difference in the ordering taking place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does BeautifulSoup find\_all() preserve tag order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654837/does-beautifulsoup-find-all-preserve-tag-order)

Comment: @hansaplast   It's answer says that `find_all` does preserve the order. I've used it in my code.

Comment: there seem to be many people who had the same question, the link I sent was just one of them. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675869/beautifulsoup-order-of-occurrence-of-tags) is another answer to your question

Comment: I had to change `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')` to `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')` to work. But it's showing up in the same/correct order as the site for me. Not sure why it would show differently for you.

Comment: @hansaplast Does your referred question mean that the ordering different? If yes, then Is there any workaround to fix this ?

Comment: @chitown88 Does replacing by `html.parser` helps to maintain the actual order?

Comment: @chitown88 I get [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uf9-x22VCZ8DbLhZFz-HG4B238YFbYRzSgv-fLJglcs/edit?usp=sharing) output which is again different from the actual one after using `html.parser`?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I’ll check again when I’m around my computer.

Comment: @chitown88 I am getting the exact ordering in the `Chrome` and unordered in the `Firefox` browser !!